# can i find audience who DID open their emails in last 6months?

Tags: dataextensions, data, sql, data-views

As per of re-engagement, i am trying to find out audience who did not open email for last 6 months, what data view captures this data?

In our case, we use a number of data extensions (for 99% emails), when i am pulling the no open email audience how i will know they were part of what data extension? They could be part of a particular data extension that we MAY not care capturing into the re-engagement audience.

We have HUNDREDS of data extension, so looking for an advice on how to pull audience for re-engagement in this case.

Comment: The difference between sent and unique opens.

Comment: Hi @Data_Kid i understand you are saying something like this: `SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _sent WHERE SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _open)` How can I relate to the data extensions because subscribers consists of ALL database while what if i want to see subscribers who did not engaged with our email from last 6 months from x, Y & z data extensions?

Comment: So far - I have this query but it is not returning any results `SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberID, s.SubscriberKey, sub.EmailAddress, s.EventDate, s.AccountID FROM _Sent s WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey WHERE DATEDIFF(day,s.EventDate,GETDATE()) > 180 AND s.SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _open) AND s.SubscriberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _click) AND s.AccountID = 'XXXXXX'`

Comment: Or should I be doing this? `SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberID, s.SubscriberKey, sub.EmailAddress, s.EventDate, s.AccountID, s.JobID
FROM _Sent s WITH (NOLOCK)

LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub
ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey

WHERE 
s.SubscriberID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _open WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) >= 180)
AND 
s.SubscriberID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriberID FROM _click WHERE DATEDIFF(day,EventDate,GETDATE()) >= 180)
AND s.AccountID = 'XXXXXX'`

Comment: Hi @Data_Kid - Just following up?